# Basement shower /ground water

Tags: water, basement, back-up

My basement shower is backing up into another party in my basement. It’s the garage that turned into a bedroom. Thoughts on how to rectify this

Comment: That must put a damper on the party.  Probably a clog in the drain pipe or bad venting.